# Count cumulative true Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, pandas-groupby

I have the following column with `True` and `False` boolean values. I want create a new column performing a cumulative sum on the `True` values and if the value is `False` reset the count, like this:

```
   bool    count
0   False  0 
1   True   1   
2   True   2
3   True   3
4   False  0
5   True   1   
6   True   2   
7   False  0   
8   False  0
```

Comment: @user17242583 This is for pandas: https://datagy.io/pandas-cumulative-sum/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done, using a series of steps:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(df['bool'].astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['bool'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df

    bool  count
0  False      0
1   True      1
2   True      2
3   True      3
4  False      0
5   True      1
6   True      2
7  False      0
8  False      0
```

Explanation:

This code creates separate groups for all consecutive true values (1's) coming before a false value (0), then, treating the trues as 1's and the falses as 0's, computes the cumulative sum for each group, then concatenates the results together.

1. `df.groupby` -

   1. `df['bool'].astype(int)` - Takes each value of `bool`, converts it to an int (true -> 1, false -> 0),
   2. `.diff()` - For each integer value, computes the difference between it an the previous value (so if the prev val was False and this is True, 1 (`1 - 0`); if prev was True and this True, 0 (`1 - 1`); etc.)
   3. `.ne(0)` - Converts all values that are *not equal to 0* to true, and zeros to false (because `(0 != 0) == False`)
   4. `.cumsum()` - Calculates cumulative sum for true (1) values. This way, all the trues before any false (0) get their own unique number, which is returned to the `groupby()` call, thus grouping separately each group of trues before a false
2. `['bool'].cumsum()` - From each group of consecutive true values (1), get the cumulative sum those 1s.

Comment: Would you care to explain or possibly break down that convoluted one-liner?

Comment: Done @Jan. Check now. (I fixed a few bugs along the way, hence the delay)

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more Pythonic way to do it, but here is a simple iterative approach:

```
current_count = 0
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if (row['bool']):
        current_count += 1
    else:
        current_count = 0
    data.at[index, 'count'] = current_count
```

Here, `data` is the dataframe that initially has one column named `bool`, then we add the `count` column!

Comment: There is a more Pythonic (really, Pandas-ic :D) way of doing it, and that's [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69982817/17242583). But yours is good to, and with `numba` might be as fast as vectorized code, so +1!

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important use this vectorized solution:

```
cumsum = df['bool'].cumsum()
df['count1'] = cumsum.sub(cumsum.where(~df['bool']).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
    bool  count  count1
0  False      0       0
1   True      1       1
2   True      2       2
3   True      3       3
4  False      0       0
5   True      1       1
6   True      2       2
7  False      0       0
8  False      0       0
```

**Explanation**:

First use cumulative sum in boolean column, `True`s are processing like `1` to variable `cumsum` (in column `cumsum`).

Then replace if `False`s by invert mask by `~` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) (in column `add_NaNs`), so possible forward filling missing values by previous values by `ffill` (in column `forward_fill_NaNs`).

It is possible use for subtracting by original Series `cumsum` (in column `subtract`).

Last if some `NaN`s in start of column (not replaced by `ffill`) use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and convert output to `integers` (in column `out`).

```
cumsum = df['bool'].cumsum()

print (df.assign(cumsum = cumsum,
                 add_NaNs = cumsum.where(~df['bool']),
                 forward_fill_NaNs= cumsum.where(~df['bool']).ffill(),
                 subtract = cumsum.sub(cumsum.where(~df['bool']).ffill()),
                 out = cumsum.sub(cumsum.where(~df['bool']).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)))
       )
    bool  count  cumsum  add_NaNs  forward_fill_NaNs  subtract  out
0  False      0       0       0.0                0.0       0.0    0
1   True      1       1       NaN                0.0       1.0    1
2   True      2       2       NaN                0.0       2.0    2
3   True      3       3       NaN                0.0       3.0    3
4  False      0       3       3.0                3.0       0.0    0
5   True      1       4       NaN                3.0       1.0    1
6   True      2       5       NaN                3.0       2.0    2
7  False      0       5       5.0                5.0       0.0    0
8  False      0       5       5.0                5.0       0.0    0
```

**Performance** (in sample data, best test in real):

```
#9k rows    
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [17]: %%timeit
    ...: current_count = 0
    ...: for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ...:     if (row['bool']):
    ...:         current_count += 1
    ...:     else:
    ...:         current_count = 0
    ...:     df.at[index, 'count1'] = current_count
    ...:     
1.06 s ± 5.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [18]: %%timeit 
    ...: df['count1'] = df.groupby(df['bool'].astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['bool'].cumsum()
    ...: 
    ...: 
2.91 ms ± 39.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [19]: %%timeit
    ...: cumsum = df['bool'].cumsum()
    ...: df['count1'] = cumsum.sub(cumsum.where(~df['bool']).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int))
    ...: 
1.38 ms ± 7.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

```
#900k rows    
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)


In [21]: %%timeit 
    ...: df['count1'] = df.groupby(df['bool'].astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['bool'].cumsum()
    ...: 
    ...: 
105 ms ± 971 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [22]: %%timeit
    ...: cumsum = df['bool'].cumsum()
    ...: df['count1'] = cumsum.sub(cumsum.where(~df['bool']).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int))
    ...: 
    ...: 
42.5 ms ± 419 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```