# Perform a cumulative count of matching values within a column based on multiple conditions and a groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df of different merchants, products and a popularity rankings, which are uneven in size.

| Merchant | Product | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Merchant 1 | apple | 1 |
| Merchant 1 | banana | 2 |
| Merchant 1 | mango | 3 |
| Merchant 1 | grapes | 4 |
| Merchant 1 | kiwi | 5 |
| Merchant 2 | orange | 1 |
| Merchant 2 | apple | 2 |
| Merchant 2 | banana | 3 |
| Merchant 2 | grapes | 4 |
| Merchant 3 | mango | 1 |
| Merchant 3 | grapes | 2 |
| Merchant 3 | orange | 3 |

I want to count the number of cumulative matching products per merchant, then return an adjusted rank (which is the cum total +1). But I only want to count the first group of matching products and only if they start at 1, with the adjusted rank resetting to 1 if the total is not > 2.

In this example the matching pattern would be `apple|banana|orange`

The ideal output would be a dataframe with the merchant, rank and adjusted rank:

| Merchant | Rank | Adjusted Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Merchant 1 | 1 | 3 |
| Merchant 2 | 1 | 4 |
| Merchant 3 | 1 | 1 |

With some help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982638/count-cumulative-true-value), i've managed to solve the problem. But what I've done feels quite inefficient. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

pattern = 'apple|banana|orange'

# Check column contains substring and create bool column
df['Match'] = np.where(df['Product'].str.contains(pattern), True, False)

# perform count on True values, resetting when False 
df['Count'] = df.groupby(df['Match'].astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['Match'].cumsum()

# filter out False values

filtered = df[df['Match'] != False]

# filter out values where rank != count, as these aren't in the 1st grouping

filtered = filtered.loc[filtered['Rank'] == filtered['Count']]

# get max rank from remaining values

filtered = filtered.groupby('Merchant')['Count'].max().reset_index(name='Adjusted Rank')

# add 1 to ranks to get maximum position, reset ranking to 1 if there aren't 2 concurrent values

filtered['Adjusted Rank'] = np.where(filtered['Adjusted Rank'] > 2, (filtered['Adjusted Rank'] + 1), 1)

# merge dfs, drop columns, drop dupes

df = df.merge(filtered, how='left', on='Merchant').fillna(1)

df = df[['Merchant','Rank','Adjusted Rank']]

df.drop_duplicates('Merchant', inplace=True)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Note sure what is the final "Rank"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
products = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']

out = (df
 .groupby('Merchant', as_index=False)
 .agg(**{'Adjusted Rank': ('Product', lambda s: s.isin(products).cummin().sum()+1)})
)
```

output:

```
     Merchant  Adjusted Rank
0  Merchant 1              3
1  Merchant 2              4
2  Merchant 3              1
```

##### rank to 1 if Adjusted Rank <= 2:

```
out['Rank'] = out['Adjusted Rank'].where(out['Adjusted Rank'].gt(2), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway, this is much better than what I had. Can I ask why the ** is needed?

Also, one slight difference in mine is that I reset the adjusted rank to 1 for cum counts that aren't > 2. Is the np.where the best way to go there, or could it be done in the same groupby?

Comment: The ** is for parameter expansion (to turn the `Adjusted Rank` in to a`Adjusted Rank=...`, which is not directly possible due to the space), for the counts <=2 to 1, you can indeed use `np.where` (or better, `pd.Series.where`), see update