# Pandas -- reset a group by counter

Tags: python, pandas

This solution does not work for me [Count cumulative true Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982638/count-cumulative-true-value;) I explicitly need to group by `id` **and** `consecBool`; the above assumes a homogenous data set with no distinct groups

How can I reset my cumsum counter when a boolean column is False?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              'consecDays': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
              'consecBool': [False, True, True, True, False, True, True],
              'expected': [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]})

df['Counter'] = df.groupby(['id', 'consecBool'])['consecDays'].cumsum()
```

`expected` is the expected outcome

```
   id  consecDays  consecBool  expected  Counter
0   1           0       False         0        0
1   1           1        True         1        1
2   1           1        True         2        2
3   1           1        True         3        3
4   1           0       False         0        0
5   1           1        True         1        4
6   1           1        True         2        5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
consecBool = df['consecBool'].eq(False).cumsum()  # or (~df['consecBool']).cumsum()
df['Counter'] = df.groupby(['id', consecBool])['consecDays'].cumsum()
print(df)

# Output
   id  consecDays  consecBool  expected  Counter
0   1           0       False         0        0
1   1           1        True         1        1
2   1           1        True         2        2
3   1           1        True         3        3
4   1           0       False         0        0
5   1           1        True         1        1
6   1           1        True         2        2
```